Forgot ubuntu vagrant ssh password
Is there any way to reset ssh password?  Could it be stored in a file somewhere?  New to ubuntu and vagrant.

More details needed. What is the version of Ubuntu? What are you SSH ing between?

If passwords could be easily bypassed, or were stored in plain text, then they would not be useful. We don't engage in pretend-security. For a Vagrant box, re-download and reinstall. Or get admin access from the host, if Vagrant offers that.

Redownloaded and reinstalled.
